# Can I connect my local Git to different server accounts?

Tags: git

I work at home and would like to connect different Gits independently from each other.
Cannot figure out if it is possible.
E.g. for work I would need to connect company's repository using my company's email. Company uses Git in Azure DevOps (former cloud VSTS or TFS)
For my personal use I would need to connect my account in GitHub or my personal account it Azure DevOps. I am doing it mainly for learning or PoC purpose.

No need to merge both, I am just the beginner with Git, so asking at least to point me to the right direction. I did not find the example that would match exactly my need.

Adding for clarification:
I want to understand how I can configure the following on my desktop using Git command line or Eclipse Git plugin:
2 independent projects both using different independent remote repos with different accounts.

Comment: You can use a GIT client like SourceTree to connect different accounts.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question as asked is yes: one Git can connect to any other Git.  Well, provided there is some internet connection, or—with `git bundle`—some sort of [sneaker-net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet) connection.

The answer to another question, about whether this would be *useful*, is more complicated.  (And the answer to a third question, whether your company might approve or not, is political rather than technical.)

Git is, in the end, all about *commits* as identified by hash IDs.  To get useful work done in separate Gits, they need to share the actual *commits* and thus the *hash IDs*.  That's why we use `git clone`: this copies the *commits* by their *hash IDs*.

When you make a clone of some other Git repository, you get *all* of its *commits* and *none* of its branches.<sup>1</sup>  The clone process receives their branch names, but *modifies* them, so that they become your *remote-tracking names*.  Your Git then creates one branch name in your copy of the repository.  This one branch name points to the *same commit* as one of their branch names, which are now your remote-tracking names.

From this point on, you do work with the commit hash IDs, using your own branch name(s), which you create based on the hash IDs stored in their branch names, which you've copied to your remote-tracking names.  You now have your own *branch names*, but all the *commits* are shared—except for any new commits that you create, and any new commits they create after you run `git clone`.

To have your Git and their Git co-ordinate, you and they need to share most of the hash IDs and commits.  So a clone of your clone, or of their clone, is good: these all share lots of hash IDs, and therefore lots of commits.

To the extent that you're cloning clones of clones of the clones that cloned clones of clones , this all works out pretty well.  It all goes wrong when you connect two *unrelated* repositories, where the hash IDs don't match up in any commits at all.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, you get all the *reachable* commits from some set of names, where the set of names is up to you.  Typically, though, you use all of their (public-visibility, branch and tag) names to create all of your names, so that you get all their commits.  Your Git copies their *tag* names and renames their *branch* names, so you share tag names, but have your own unique branch names.

All of this can be controlled, but that's Advanced Git, not Git 101.

Comment: Thank  you for the response.
I added some clarification to the question:
Adding for clarification:
I want to understand how I can configure the following on my desktop using Git command line or Eclipse Git plugin:
2 independent projects both using different independent remote repos with different accounts.

Comment: I know nothing about Eclipse but have been advised that what works in Git doesn't work in Eclipse, so you might want to ask Eclipse people about that. As far as *independent* projects go in Git, you should use two separate Git repositories to handle that. It *is* possible to wedge multiple independent projects into a single Git repository, but there's no good reason to do that.

Comment: I am getting closer. This what tutorial says in 
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup :
These commands can be done only once:
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
But: "If you want to override this with a different name or email address for specific projects, you can run the command without the --global option when you’re in that project".
So now I need to find out how exactly this can be done.

Comment: The `user.name` and `user.email` settings are used only for *making new commits*. They go into the new commit's metadata. They are not used when cross-connecting one Git to another Git. Instead, when you connect one Git to another, you choose a *protocol* such as `ssh` or `https`. The next step after choosing the protocol is protocol-dependent, but for both of those cases, consists of selecting a *user name* and a *host to connect to*. It's then up to the host to verify that you are who you claim to be, and that's done without looking at `user.name` or `user.email`.